# How do I get the register values for a particular frame?

Tags: x86, solaris

```
> ffffff00bbcc8c40::findstack -v
stack pointer for thread ffffff00bbcc8c40: ffffff00bbcc86b0
[ ffffff00bbcc86b0 _resume_from_idle+0xf4() ]
  ffffff00bbcc86e0 swtch+0x145()
  ffffff00bbcc8710 cv_wait+0x61(ffffff1a4e538bb8, ffffff1a4e538a80)
  ffffff00bbcc8770 cv_wait_sig+0x26e(ffffff1a4e538bb8, ffffff1a4e538a80)
  ffffff00bbcc8850 so_dequeue_msg+0x2a4(ffffff1a4e538a60, ffffff00bbcc88b8, ffffff00bbcc8980, ffffff00bbcc88c0, 40)
  ffffff00bbcc8920 so_recvmsg+0x1af(ffffff1a4e538a60, ffffff00bbcc89b0, ffffff00bbcc8980, ffffff198dc34db0)
  ffffff00bbcc8960 socket_recvmsg+0x3d(ffffff1a4e538a60, ffffff00bbcc89b0, ffffff00bbcc8980, ffffff198dc34db0)
  ffffff00bbcc8a40 ksocket_recv+0x124(ffffff1a4e538a60, ffffff00bbcc8aac, 4, 40, ffffff00bbcc8a58, ffffff198dc34db0)
  ffffff00bbcc8a90 smb_sorecv+0x4e(ffffff1a4e538a60, ffffff00bbcc8aac, 4)
  ffffff00bbcc8ad0 smb_session_xprt_gethdr+0x35(ffffff23b1784c38, ffffff00bbcc8ae8)
  ffffff00bbcc8b20 smb_session_message+0x214(ffffff23b1784c38)
  ffffff00bbcc8b60 smb_session_receiver+0x8c(ffffff23b1784c38)
  ffffff00bbcc8b90 smb_server_receiver+0x28(ffffff23d5ff1ce8)
  ffffff00bbcc8c20 taskq_d_thread+0xb1(ffffff19f34ec258)
  ffffff00bbcc8c30 thread_start+8()
```

How do I get the register values at the time of each function call ?
I think we can use the frame pointer, but I don't know how.

Update:This is not live analysis.This is for a  kernel crash dump analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Knowning only the frame pointer would help you not. EBP would be the same before a `XORL %EAX, %EAX`, and after it. Then, it happens that the x86 instruction set itself is not tied to any particular ABI. This means that any attempt to do this would require you to know EIP, EBP (from there you can get EBP and EIP of every other frame), and the ABI, and even then, some (or all) values would be impossible to retrieve, depending on the ABI. EBP itself is a general purpose register, so frames are not even mandatory (see `-fomit-frame-pointer`)!

For this, lets assume the [cdecl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) ABI (used by most C compilers for most C code). To investigate the current function's registers, just view them. They can't be any different. Then, you need to be able to return from the function. If your program crashed and you can't do this, then you're screwed. Just right after the function's return, you can look at all registers, except for EAX, ECX, and EDX. Those three are "caller-saved", that is, the function that just returned could have modified and not restored them. Their contents are most likely lost.

You can then continue, returning and investigating everything but EAX, ECX, and EDX, up all the way where you want. Anyway, it's a better idea to just debug by stepping and stuff of the like. I don't think you would be even able to return from the functions after all (GDB can't, AFAIK).

Comment: In `gdb` you can use the `finish` command (`f`) to single-step until the current function returns.  You can't in general return without running the rest of the function, unless you know that `ESP` is currently pointing to the right place.  Then you can continue execution at the start of the function's epilogue.  Also, gdb has some way of recording history, letting you step backwards in time.  I forget what it is; I found out it existed from one of Jester's comments, but I haven't had a need for it since then, so I still haven't tried it myself.

Comment: I missed mentioning it before ,this is for a kernel crash dump analysis.

Comment: @Iceman: That's an even worse situation! I mean, debugging the kernel can be a considerably different process sometimes. Then, it happens that, as you have a crash dump and not a running process, there's no way for you to return from the crashing function.